# Edit python31 file and it opens notepad and starts python26

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am in python31,

then I go to file open i left click to open file
and it opens in notepad(simple text editor)python31

The moment it opens the notepad, it starts python26

I thought it has something to open with, and I have changed that to python31
And it still opens python26

EDIT:

The file is created by python26, but it is not executable.

Comment: You should phrase the question like this: this is what I do (precise order of mouse clicks); this is what happens; this is what I want to happen instead. For example, I don't understand whether you want to open the file with notepad or not. I also don't understand: when you open the file with notepad, does Python get started automatically? That would be very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing here, the question it not very clear.

It sounds like the .py extension in Windows is associated with the Python 2.6 runtime. (This normally get setup this way during installation of Python on Windows). You can change this by updating the associated file extensions and programs in Windows.

By double clicking on the file it is not opening the file for editing but instead running it.   If you want to edit the file you have to either right-click and select an approriate edit action or open the file from your editor's 'open file' action. (Or change the .py extension to open in your favourite editor)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, and right clicking and changing edit options didn't solve it. You can try repairing python31 installation with running the msi installer and selecting it as the default python